# using paper-datatable-card in a custom-tag

Tags: polymer

```html
//index.html

<html>
<head>
   <link rel="import" href="test-table.html">
 </head> 
<body>
  <template is="dom-bind" id="index">
     <test-table data="{{data}}" ></test-table>
  </template>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
Polymer({
        is: "test-table",
  properties : {
    data : {type : Array},
          }
    /*I dont know where should I put this stuff
      "queryForIds:"
      "getByIds :"
      "set:"
      "length:0"
   */
    });
```

```html
<dom-module id="test-table">
  <template>
     <paper-datatable-card id="datatableCard" header="Users" page-size="10" data-source="{{data}}" id-property="_id" selected-ids="{{selectedIds}}">
        <paper-datatable id="datatable" data='{{data}}' selectable multi-selection selected-items="{{selectedItems}}">
                    <paper-datatable-column header="Id" property="_id" sortable>
                        <template>
                            <span>{{value}}</span>
                        </template>
                    </paper-datatable-column>
          </paper-datatable>
     </paper-datatable-card>
   </template>
</dom-module>
```

as part of single page application I am using “paper-datatable-card” in my own custom-tag. I able to display the records but I’m not getting where I have to put the code for pagination. And I don’t want to put all records into dataSource at a time.
Any help is appreciated,
Thank you,
Venkat.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. Can you please add some actual code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish?

Comment: You can edit your question. Please add the code to your question. Code in comments is quite cumbersome to read.

Comment: please check the code mentioned above

Comment: Did you check this example https://github.com/David-Mulder/paper-datatable/blob/master/demo/paper-datatable-card/full-implementation.html#L119?

Comment: i'm using the same example  but as a custom-element. So I am unable to put the code from lines 117 to 133 in my custom elements as it doesnt support dom-bind

Answer (score 0):

From within your Polymer component, you can set `data` in the `ready` method:

```
ready: function() {
        this.data =  {
            queryForIds: function(sort, page, pageSize){
                // implement me
            },
            getByIds: function(ids){
               // implement me
            },
            set: function(item, property, value){
               // implement me
            },
            length:0
        };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comment question:

> So I am unable to put the code from lines 117 to 133 in my custom elements as it doesnt support dom-bind

Answer (in Polymer 2.0) you can do it in your component constructor all the methods and all the data variables:

```
class YourComponent extends Polymer.Element {
    contructor() {
       super();
       //in case if you use paper-datatable-card
       this.data = {
         get: function (sort, page, pageSize) {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        const exampleData = [
                            { 'name': 'someName1' },
                            { 'name': 'someName2' }
                        ];
                        resolve(exampleData);
                    });
                },
          set: function(item, property, value){...},
          length: 1
       };
       //in case if you use paper-datatable only then without get or set properties
       this.data = [ { name: 'someName' } ];
    }
}
```